# focusout getting called multiple times

Tags: jquery

I want an ajax call when the user leave the input with the class selector name "data". My problem is the focusout event is called multiple times.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var test2=0;
$(document).on('focus', '.data', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.focusout(function(){
            $('div.debug2').text(test2++);
    });     
}); 
  });
```

Here is my html :

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
 <tr id='user_${user.id}' class="datarow">
  <td><input class="data" type="text" name="role" value="${user.role }"></td>
  <td><input class="data" type="text" name="fullName" value="${user.fullName }"></td>                                  
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
<div class="debug2">Focus Out</div>
```

What did I do wrong? If there is any way better to handle this, let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up a focusout event handler each time something gains focus. So, each time a field loses focus, you'll end up with as many events as the number of times any field was focused.

You should setup the focusout event handler only once on the document, so remove the code from the `on` function and put it besides it.

Comment: I thought $(document).on('focus', '.data', function().. means that it's only the class selector name "data" ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem here is that each time the `focus` handler is called, one **new** `focusout` handler gets created, and in the end they add up.

Comment: Ohhh I see, I thought that when a  new focusout is created on a selector , it remove the previous ones.

Comment: Nope, it stays. But you may be interested in the [jQuery one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function however - it creates an event handler which is executed at most one time.

Answer (score 0):

no need to bind to focus when all you need is the focusout event

***changed the code to test if the value has changed

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('focusout', '.data', function() {
       var current = $(this),
           oldVal = current.data("oldVal");
       if(this.value === oldVal)
       { 
         return;
       }
       current.data("oldVal", this.value);
       //make ajax call
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: I know but I want to compare the old with new value to decide whether or not to make an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

your problem that every time you focus on the object you attach another .focusout event exponentially.

use

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var test2=0;
    $(document).on('focusout', '.data', function() {
    //do whatever you need
    }); 
  });
```

or either unbind the previous event you set a new one, but that is a bad code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var test2=0;
        $(document).on('focus', '.data', function() {
        $('.data').unbind('focusout');
        $(document).on('focusout', '.data', function() {
          });
      });
```